# Stacked objects, bad practice?

Tags: php

Given a User class:

```
class User
{
    private $right;

    public function getUsername() { }

    public function login() { }

    public function getRight()
    {
        return $this->right;
    }
}
```

he has rights:

```
class Right
{
    public function isAdmin()
    {
        return true or false;
    }

    public function isGuest()
    {
        return true or false;
    }
}
```

so whenever I want to get his right, I write:

```
$user->getRight()->isGuest();
```

I dont know if its good or not. First it seems to be natural, because `right` belongs to an `user`.
On the other hand, I type too much. What if `$user->getobj1()->getObj2()->getRight()->isadmin();` ? What if there are 25 stacked objects? And I feel I break Demeter of law. So is that good or bad practice? `Right` should be a standalone thing?

Comment: `return true or false` - Eh?

Comment: also the word role would make more sense then right

Comment: If that's all those methods do, why not just store them as booleans (or binaries) in the user table/object? `is_admin` and `is_guest`?

Comment: @JeremyJackson. I don't agree: as currently structured, he can change the true|false condition of the `isAdmin()` method of a given `Right`, so it applies to any `User` having this `Right`.

Comment: @John Smith. I often use this kind of chaining methods, and it's almost a rule in some worlds like Drupal. But I confess I don't know if there is a limit.